# Selecting the count of rows on second table based on foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this table of albums and images. Images have a column named `album_id` which takes the album ID they are sitting on. So far so good.

Now I'm in need to select information from the Albums table and I also need the count of images for each album row. I tried using a `LEFT JOIN` and a `COUNT(*)`, but it would return only one row, which is highly inefficient for my case.

This is the original query I'm using which wont return anything count related:

```
SELECT album_id, album_name, album_preview, album_owner, album_time, album_access 
FROM imgzer_albums WHERE album_owner = SOME_VALUE
```

And this is the query with the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.album_id, a.album_name, a.album_preview, a.album_owner, a.album_time, a.album_access, COUNT(i.*) AS images 
FROM imgzer_albums a 
LEFT JOIN imgzer_images i 
    ON a.album_id = i.album_id 
WHERE album_owner = SOME_VALUE
```

How do I get the images count for each corresponding album ID without being limited to one result only?

Comment: dont you think you are missing the `group by` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT a.album_id, a.album_name, a.album_preview, a.album_owner, a.album_time, a.album_access, COUNT(i.*) AS images 
FROM imgzer_albums a 
LEFT JOIN imgzer_images i 
    ON a.album_id = i.album_id 
WHERE album_owner = SOME_VALUE
GROUP BY a.album_id
```

Comment: You have to group every selected field.

Comment: Simple and effective! Thanks! @wumpz This is not MSSQL, so that's not needed here I guess. Well, it works so..

Answer (score 0):

a solution without grouping is a  correlated query:

```
SELECT a.album_id, a.album_name, a.album_preview, a.album_owner, a.album_time, a.album_access, 
(select COUNT(*) from imgzer_images i where a.album_id = i.album_id) AS images 
FROM imgzer_albums a 
WHERE album_owner = SOME_VALUE
```